# Input box as "date" on web when model is "int"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core v2 and Razorpages

In SQL (and in the model) I have a field `[FrDt]` of data type "int" where I need to store a date value (as int) (I can't change the data type in SQL)

If I set `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` in the model I automatially get an input "date" type on web. but when I submit,  the values are not sent to the server. probably because the value is of type date and the field is int

RAZORPAGE

```
<input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.FrDt" class="form-control" />
```

MODEL

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public int FrDt { get; set; }
```

My intention was to convert the value entered on the webpage to an int like this:

CS PAGE

```
AgrRow.FrDt = int.Parse(AgrRow.FrDt.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

But the date value entered is not sent to the server, instead 0 (zero) is sent so the parse do not work. If I remove the [DataType(DataType.Date)] from the model I get a normal inputbox on web and the value I enter is sent to the server.

btw: I am using Chrome and the built in date picker

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

UPDATE - Post Method Returns 0, probably because the default value in SQL is zero

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveNewRowAsync() {
 Console.WriteLine("FRDT = " + AgrRow.FrDt.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What does the value of your `int` relate to (ticks?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: How is your `int` value interpreted as a date - for example the number of `Ticks` since `01/01/0001`?

Comment: You are editing data, therefore you use a view model, and that view model can contain a `DateTime` property. In the controller methods you can convert you `int` to `DateTime` and vice versa in the POST method when you save the data model

Comment: Why not adding a property to your viewmodel, which does the `int -> Date` and `Date -> int` conversion for you?

Comment: As others have suggested, use Date in the viewmodel and convert it to/from an int only when interacting with the database. Problem solved.

Comment: thank you all for your comments, but my problem is that when the input field is of type 'date' all I get in the post request is 0 (zero),

Comment: Its not the input type that needs to be changed - its the property type that need to be changed - it MUST be `DateTime`

Comment: If my inputField is of type "date" the value entered on web is not submitted. all other values work fine using [BindProperty] in the Page Model.

Answer (score 0):

Use View Model to bind view instead of actual model, which will contain DateTime type of property. Then Map View Model to actual Entity Model.

View Model:

```
class AgrRowVM
{
  public DateTime? FrDt {get; set;}
  //Rest of the properties
}
```

Model:

```
class AgrRow
{
  public int? FrDt {get; set;}
  //Rest of the properties
}
```

After posting values to serverside map View Model to Orginal model.

```
if(agrRowVMObj.FrDt.HasValue)
{
  agrRowObj.FrDt = int.Parse(agrRowVMObj.FrDt.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```

Comment: I can't get that to work, I am using Razorpages and not sure if you are suggesting that I add a public property into the pageModel? do I need to bind that property using the [BindProperty] sorry for not understanding.