# Input box as “date” on web when model is “int” (again)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, model, type-conversion, razor-pages

I decided to create a new post here instead of the other post which was a bit confusing.  ([Input box as "date" on web when model is "int"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815746/input-box-as-date-on-web-when-model-is-int))

In this post I have added the code I use.

The problem is that in the SQL server the field FrDr is of type int and I need the user on the webpage to enter in a input field of type "date"

If I add  [DataType(DataType.Date)] to the model i get the input date type autmoatically. but not if I add it to the Page Model

How can I change my code so that the user get an input field of type date that save the date value as an int to SQL.

MODEL AGR.CS

```
namespace DateTest.VismaModels {

    public partial class Agr {


        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Actor")]
        public int AgrActNo { get; set; }

        public int AgrNo { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "From Date")]
        public int FrDt { get; set; }

    }
}
```

PAGE MODEL

```
   namespace DateTest.Pages {

    public class IndexModel : PageModel {
        private readonly DateTest.VismaModels.F0001Context _context;


        public IndexModel(DateTest.VismaModels.F0001Context context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public bool ShowMessage => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);

        [TempData]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Agr AgrRow { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id) {


            if (id == null) {
                Console.WriteLine("New");
                AgrRow = new Agr();
                AgrRow.AgrNo = _context.Agr.Select(q => q.AgrNo).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max() + 1;
                //AgrRow.FrDt = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                //var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count > 0).ToList();
                var errors = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
                Message += "Model not valid : " + errors;
                return Redirect("~/Activities/index");
            }
            return Page();
        }



        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveNewRowAsync() {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                //var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count > 0).ToList();
                var errors = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
                Message += "Model not valid : " + errors;
                return Redirect("~/index");
            }


            _context.Add(AgrRow);

            try {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
                throw;

            }
            Message += "Saved";
            return RedirectToPage("/index");
        }


    }



}
```

RAZOR PAGE

```
@page
@model DateTest.Pages.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Activities";
}

<h2>Activities</h2>

@if (Model.ShowMessage) {<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        @Model.Message
    </div>
}

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="AgrRow.AgrNo" />


    <table class="table">

        <tbody>

            <tr>

                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.AgrActNo" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.FrDt" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.ToDt" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.FrTm" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.ToTm" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.CustNo" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.ProdNo" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.Descr" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.NoInvoAb" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.Price" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.Am" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.Fin" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AgrRow.Invo" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" value="Save New" asp-page-handler="saveNewRow" asp-route-id="@Model.AgrRow.AgrNo" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Create
                                </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE

If I add the following to the Page Model

```
public DateTime FrDt { get; set; }
```

And print out the result in the post method like this

```
Console.WriteLine("FRDT = " + FrDt);
Console.WriteLine("AGRROW FRDT = " + AgrRow.FrDt);
```

I get this

```
FRDT = 0001-01-01 00:00:00
AGRROW FRDT = 0
```

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` just adds `type="date"` to your input. You cannot bind a date to an `int`. Use a view model which contains a `DateTime` property (and map the `int` to the `DateTime` in the GET method and vice versa in the POST method.

Comment: it does not work, if I change the input field to "date" I get zero in return when posting

Comment: Again (and this is just repeating all the comments you got on the last question) - the **property** of the model need to be `DateTime`  - i.e. you create a view model with `public DateTime FrDt { get; set; }`

Comment: see my updated post  (bottom)

Comment: In your Agr class you need `[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "From Date")]
        public DateTime FrDt { get; set; }`. Then when you save to the DB, convert that to your integer representation (I assume the int represents milliseconds since 1970 or something like that?). When you retrieve from the database, convert it back to a DateTime again. Not sure what adding a DateTime property to the main PageModel achieves, since it appears you haven't got that property on your form

Comment: Please provide answer with code because I seem to have tried that. Se my referring question

Comment: In the referring question you state you had `public int FrDt { get; set; }` which is int, not DateTime. I don't see any of your code where you changed it to DateTime. It's also worth using your browser's network tab to double-check exactly what the page is _sending_ to the server (not what it's parsing it into). Maybe try (temporarily) using a plain textbox where you just type the date string in, rather than the `input type="date"` style of field.

Comment: Why do you want me to use DateTime in the Agr Model. in SQL it is int

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In my Agr Model I add a temporary field FrDt2 which is of DateTime and use the [NotMapped] annotation so it does not send it to sql

```
[NotMapped]
public DateTime FrDt2 { get; set; }
```

And in my Page model I convert FrDt2 to int before adding it to FrDt.

```
AgrRow.FrDt = int.Parse(AgrRow.FrDt2.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

And, to show an existing item from SQL in the input date box I convert it back to int like this

```
AgrRow.FrDt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(AgrRow.FrDt.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```